# Android C++ IPC using Boost.Interprocess - should it work?

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk

Background:

I have working C++ code on linux that uses Boost IPC to access shared memory, and I want to port it to android. I downloaded and built the Boost-for-Android project found here: https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android.

Problem:

However when I try to create a boost named mutex like this:

```
boost::interprocess::named_mutex named_mtx(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "my_mutex");
```

I get an exception saying "no such file or directory" with a native code 2.

Additional information:

When I searched for how to use shared memory on android, it looks ashmem and Binder are popular methods, and I can't find references to them at all in the ported Boost IPC code.

Questions:

1. What is the reason for the "no such file or directory" error?
2. Can someone confirm that the Boost-for-Android IPC part works?

Comment: Very good question. I'm interested in this too. Did you try ruling out permissions? (Can you run the process as root?). Perhaps the shmem kernel bits are protected (or in the worst case not present).

Comment: The process is run with root access. I will check if the shared memory kernel bits are present (but then how did my code compile?).

Comment: Cross compilation _implies_ that you just compile at a (hopefully compatible) set of kernel headers/system libraries. As always, modules might be black-listed so might even go missing across a reboot. And think of rmmod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Boost does not look for a common place where to share data on Android. It was not built this way. To make it work modify the file

```
    /boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp
```

Find the following line an add /sdcard

```
    const char *names[]={ "/sdcard", ......
```

After doing that use the library and give to your application Read/Write external storage permission.

You are good to go.

PD: Please be carefull. I have problems using Mutex and conditional variables in Android because the process was taking 100% the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the way provided by @user3645767 but it didn't work. But I solved it by revision the file `'interprocess/detail/shared_dir_helpers.hpp'`
line 109
to change the `dir_path` in `get_shared_dir_root()`

```
#elif defined __ANDROID__
    dir_path="/data"
#else
    dir_path="/tmp"
```

Comment: To avoid any changes in boost codes just simply add define to cpp flags:

    -DBOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_PATH=\"/data/vendor/me/shmem\"